# How to restore data from XML into Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, serialization

I saved the data as shown below, now I want to restore the XML data into the corresponding text boxes.

```
CustomerData customer = new CustomerData();    
customer.FirstName = first_name.Text;    
customer.RegNo = reg_no.Text;    
customer.Department = dept.Text;    
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomerData));    

using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Data.xml", FileMode.Create)) {
    xs.Serialize(fs, customer);
}

MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
```

Comment: you mean how to deserialize()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomerData));
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Data.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    CustomerData customer = (CustomerData)xs.Deserialize(fs);  
    first_name.Text = customer.FirstName;    
    reg_no.Text = customer.RegNo;    
    dept.Text = customer.Department; 
}
```

*UPDATE* If you want to save history of customer data changes and load last one, then save and load list of CustomerData objects:

```
private List<CustomerData> GetCustomers(string filename)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filename))
        return new List<CustomerData>();

    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<CustomerData>));
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        return (List<CustomerData>)xs.Deserialize(fs);
}

public void SaveCustomers(string filename, List<CustomerData> customers)
{
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<CustomerData>));
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
        xs.Serialize(fs, customers);
}
```

And use it to save:

```
List<CustomerData> customers = GetCustomers(@"D:\Data.xml");
CustomerData customer = new CustomerData();
customer.FirstName = first_name.Text;
customer.RegNo = reg_no.Text;
customer.Department = dept.Text;
customers.Add(customer);
SaveCustomers(@"D:\Data.xml", customers);
```

And load:

```
var customer = GetCustomers(@"D:\Data.xml").LastOrDefault();
if (customer != null)
{
    first_name.Text = customer.FirstName;
    reg_no.Text = customer.RegNo;
    dept.Text = customer.Department;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro :) need one more help? When i save it again first data is overwrite by the next saved data. I want to append the saving data.